# Dependabot alerts: severity vulnerabilities not resolving for those npm audit showing No fix available

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm-vulnerabilities

After doing the npm audit most of them were resolved by the npm audit fix but some got No Fix Available, For those, I tried installing that dependency but could not resolve it.[See this screenshot of audit report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJD8s.png)

Comment: "No fix available" means you _can't_ resolve it, you either have to tolerate it or migrate to other dependencies.

Comment: @jonrsharpe migrate to other dependencies means installing those dependencies, eq. convert-excel-to-json  *
      Depends on vulnerable versions of magicli
      Depends on vulnerable versions of xlsx
For that I tried installing these but not able to resolve those